# add node fails w/ Azure WSFC 2012 for SQL2012 AlwaysOn Availability Grps

Tags: sql-server, azure, failovercluster, alwayson

Adding  node fails Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster for AlwaysOn Availability Groups in all AZURE, is leaving an apparent phantom VM node. How can I cleanup up?

Server property for target server VM is flagged as "clustered", but is not.  There was another node added successfully, but when trying again to add the node , that failed earlier, does not work, as cluster manager reports back that target "xxxxx server is already clustered".

I evicted the the single node, then "destroyed cluster". Then created anewly named cluster. Added one node, but when trying to add the "problem" sql server VM, I get same return msg : "server is already in a cluster".  When I remote into the target sql Azure VM, server manager shows the server as "Clustered". I can not find any way to clean this failed operation up.

When I open FO cluster mgr on the SQL VM, I see red-x'ed the cluster name of the cluster I had previously "destroyed".  Same VNET, same subnet.  Validates OK on cluster build up to point of failure when trying a add 2nd SQL VM node to cluster.

Answer (score 0):

No solution was found after rambling thru msdn, technet. Had to delete azure vm,s completely, but note that in the 
same cloud viewed thru ms new portal, parts still are displayed in those pages. Like Loose random balloons drifting around azure chaos...